# How to convert a dtype from object to int in Python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data file and when I run `df.dtypes` on it, it says that the type is an object, but to plot it it need to be an `integer`, `float`, `double`, etc. The data actually consists of three columns of numbers, like this:

```
123 12345 0.9484 
123 12345 0.8746 
123 12345 0.4838 
123 12345 0.4837
```

How do I go about transforming the data so that it can be plotted with pandas?

Comment: check `.astype()` method/function

Comment: When I try to convert the data to a float, it gives me an error saying "could not convert string to float: '1703 73048 0.199'".

Comment: could you post the output of `print(df.columns.tolist())`? There must be something wrong with your data... How do you read / generate your data frame?

Comment: the result is a string: ['Day Time Usage']

Comment: you are reading CSV file right?

Comment: it is a .txt file, but I am reading it as a csv file

Comment: use `sep='\s+'` as a parameter in your `pd.read_csv()` function

Comment: Now i get this error when I do df.plot() : no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Datatype conversion in [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

This answer assumes you have the [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org) library, you are computing in [`iPython`](https://ipython.org) and that your file is `csv`-ish.

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
from cStringIO import StringIO

fake_csv = '''123 12345 0.9484
123 12345 0.8746
123 12345 0.4838
123 12345 0.4837'''

# Create data frame, fake csv for example only
# normally you would use pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv', ...)
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(fake_csv), sep='\s+', header=None)

print 'DataFrame:\n{}\n\nData Types:\n{}'.format(df, df.dtypes)

df.plot()
```

---

```
DataFrame:
     0      1       2
0  123  12345  0.9484
1  123  12345  0.8746
2  123  12345  0.4838
3  123  12345  0.4837

Data Types:
0      int64
1      int64
2    float64
dtype: object
```

[image: df plot]

<sub>Note: the last `dtype:object` is the datatype of the `Series` in `df.dtypes` not of the types in `df`.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with parameters: `sep='\s+'` (arbitrary whitespace) and `engine='python'`(because warning):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""Day Time Usage
123 12345 0.9484
123 12345 0.8746
123 12345 0.4838
123 12345 0.4837"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep='\s+', engine='python')

print df
   Day   Time   Usage
0  123  12345  0.9484
1  123  12345  0.8746
2  123  12345  0.4838
3  123  12345  0.4837

print df.dtypes
Day        int64
Time       int64
Usage    float64
dtype: object

print df.index
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype='int64')
```